# Setup Project does not replace assembly files

Tags: installation, windows-installer

1. I have a Windows Application project
   (A.exe) that calls another project
   Class Library (B.dll).
2. A.exe has a button (myButton) that
   calls the method Method1 from B.dll.
3. To install the application I created
   a Setup project ASetup.vdproj, whose
   Primary Output is project A.
4. After compiling the setup, the
   installation runs without any
   problems, when A.exe starts and I
   click myButton, the aplication gives
   no error.
5. Then I changed B.dll and added a new
   method Method2.
6. myButton is now calling Method2 from
   B.dll instead of Method1.
7. I increased the version of A.exe and
   increment the version of
   ASetup.vdproj, but do not increase
   the version of B.dll.
8. After installing the application I
   noticed I had two installations of
   A.exe in Control Panel -> Add /
   Remove Programmes.
9. When running A.exe and click
   myButton I obtain an error, "The
   method Method2 was not found in
   B.dll", it means that the setup does
   not replace B.dll during
   installation.
10. I ran the uninstall and I noticed
     that the files were not removed
     from disk.

**My question is:**

Why doesn’t the second installation update B.dll?
If the version of B.dll is incremented, B.dll will be replaced during the installation, but the problem is that my current project has many external assemblies, which is difficult to control if they have been modified or not. Basically, what I want is that all assembly files are replaced in each installation.

I await feedback from all of you.
Thank you for all the attention.

Answer (score 6):

The 2 entries in Add/Remove Programs tells me that you changed the ProductCode property but didn't have a valid row in the Upgrade Table to properly define a Major Upgrade.  MSI treats this as 2 different products that happen to get installed to the same directory.   When you uninstall one of the two products the files remain until you uninstall the other product.

The DLL not being overwritten suggests to me that you didn't change the AssemblyFileVersion attribute from one build to another.   The first install copies in 1.0.0.0 and the second install says "1.0.0.0 is already there, nothing to do here" and skips it.

Answer (score 2):

Besides the problem mentioned by @Christopher Painter, there is most likely another problem: The setup project created with Visual Studio (2008) will only replace files if the version number has been incremented. The obvious solution would be to just increment all version numbers; however, this might not always be what you want.

The behavior of the .msi file is basically determined by the moment when the [RemoveExistingProducts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371197.aspx) action is executed. Installers created with VS 2008 schedule this action *after* the new product has been installed. Modified assemblies whose version has not been incremented therefore don't get replaced. Some more details about the update behavior are described in this thread:

> [`RemovePreviousVersions=True` but previous version is not removed from the target machine](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformssetup/thread/9ce5da29-3f37-4e7f-a548-1cbeb4a3e0a3)

To change the behavior, you can patch the created .msi file so that the [RemoveExistingProducts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371197.aspx) action is executed *before* the new product gets installed (this actually has been the behavior if you created the setup with Visual Studio 2005). Patching can e.g. be done using a small VBScript that runs as a post-built step:

```
Dim objInstaller
Dim objDatabase
Dim objView
Dim objResult

Dim strPathMsi 

If WScript.Arguments.Count <> 1 Then
    WScript.Echo "Usage: cscript fixRemovePreviousVersions.vbs <path to MSI>"
    WScript.Quit -1
End If

strPathMsi = WScript.Arguments(0)

Set objInstaller = CreateObject("WindowsInstaller.Installer")
Set objDatabase = objInstaller.OpenDatabase(strPathMsi, 1)
Set objView = objDatabase.OpenView("UPDATE InstallExecuteSequence SET Sequence=1450 WHERE Action='RemoveExistingProducts'")

WScript.Echo "Patching install sequence: UPDATE InstallExecuteSequence SET Sequence=1450 WHERE Action='RemoveExistingProducts'"
objView.Execute
objDatabase.Commit

WScript.Quit 0
```

Comment: I've been down that road with VDPROJ and in no time you'll hav dozens of these postbuild scripts to get around the fact that VDPROJ sucks. Dump VDPROJ now for another tool (WiX or IS 2010 LE ) and you'll have a longer life. :-)   BTW, the CM Expert in me says that it's insane to intentionally ship 2 MSI's with different assemblies that have the same file version.   Traceability is critical.

Comment: @Christopher Painter: That's all very true.

Comment: What is the significance of this "SET Sequence=1450" command? Is there a way to look at the "database" that I assume is embedded in the MSI somewhere?

Comment: @Qwertie: This changes the moment when the RemoveExistingProducts action will be executed during setup. If you want to look at the MSI database, you can use Orca (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370557%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: @Qwertie:  The .MSI file *is* a database.