# Not able to upgrade to TeeChart 4.1.2012.01310 via WindowsInstaller

Tags: c#, .net, teechart

The mentioned version of the TeeChart was released at the End of January 2013. The included TeeChart.dll has version (e.g. the .net40 one): 4.1.2012.1312. Unfortunately this version is smaller than all previous version of the TeeChart released in 2012. Actually the version should be 4.1.2013.1312, but it is not. Because of the version mismatch the WindowsInstaller is not able to upgrade this library. It uninstalls the previous one, but doesn't install this one, because its version is older as e.g. 4.1.2012.2283.

So does anybody (specially Steema guys are asked here) has any idea how I'm supposed to distribute that by a normal Visual Studio vdproj setup???

What I'm currently doing is: I modify the 'File' table within the MSI file and set the value of the 'Version' column for the TeeChart to the correct version and it works. Unfortunately this version is the last one, which my license includes, so I'm not able to skip it and move to any of the following versions of 2013 without buying a new license.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, bear in mind that *.vdproj projects are a deprecated Microsoft technology as you can read [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/buckh/archive/2011/03/17/visual-studio-setup-projects-vdproj-will-not-ship-with-future-versions-of-vs.aspx?Redirected=true):

> The Visual Studio setup projects will not ship again – VS 2010 was the
>   last release with support for it.  So, you’ll want to make plans to
>   migrate to something else.

Having that in mind I can think of the following options:

1. That's an unfortunate coincidence. However, if you stick with *.vdproj, you might need to upgrade your TeeChart subscription to get an up to date assembly.
2. Alternatively, you can use a workaround similar to what [0xA3’s answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4087051/setup-project-does-not-replace-assembly-files).
3. Considering that *.vdproj is an obsolete technology and given OxA3's answer, you could upgrade your installer builder toll as suggested in [Christopher Painter's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4087051/setup-project-does-not-replace-assembly-files#comment4395633_4087137):

> I've been down that road with VDPROJ and in no time you'll hav dozens
>   of these postbuild scripts to get around the fact that VDPROJ sucks.
>   Dump VDPROJ now for another tool (WiX or IS 2010 LE ) and you'll have
>   a longer life. :-)